# If $A$ is an adjacency matrix of a labeled multi-digraph is the $(i,j)^{th}$ coordinate of $A^n$ the number of directed $n$-walks from $i$ to $j$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, directed-graphs, adjacency-matrix

If $A$ is an adjacency matrix of a labeled multi-digraph is the $(i,j)^{th}$ coordinate of $A^n$ the number of directed walks from $i$ to $j$? I know this is true when $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a digraph, but what about for multi-digraphs i.e. directed graphs that can have loops and multiple arrows connecting adjacency vertices. Where just to review if $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a labeled multi-digraph $[A]_{i,j}$ is equal to the number of arrows with vertex tail $i$ and vertex head $j$. For instance the picture bellow shows an example of such an adjacency matrix for a multi-digraph:

[image]

Comment: Can you follow through the usual induction proof for this statement, and see if the induction step is still valid?

Comment: @Joppy Yes, it does. However, I'm not sure if the user who's asked the question is aware of the induction proof. It makes for a nice exercise to try proving the statement for a simple undirected graph using induction. The generalization to multi-digraphs immediately follows.